# Is there any excel formula that finds if value of a cell is in the column of another sheet?

Tags: python, excel, excel-formula, xlwings

There is an xlsx file with such structure:

[image]

[image]

I need to make lines of sheet with reviews, where is the recipe_id that is not in the sheet of recipes, red. Is there any formula in Excel, which can verify if there is an recipe, which has the same id with recipe_id in review, that I can paste to cells using xlwings? How to paste it? Is there another way to solve this problem using xlwings?

Answer (score 1):

Apologies in advance, I can answer **only half** of your question. Turning a row red if its ID is not in a list is a simple conditional format. I can explain the conditional format. Excel allows applying conditional formats via VBA. I won't go into that because your question is specifically about applying it via xlwings. I can't address that part because I don't know xlwings at all. But this might at least get you started. Someone who knows how to set a conditional format in Excel via xlwings might give you the other half.

We want a format condition that returns True if the recipe ID is not found on the Recipe page.

In your example, recipe IDs are in Column C on both the Reviews page and the Recipes page.

On the Reviews page, the statement `MATCH($C2, Recipes!$C:$C, 0)` returns `#NA!` if no match is found on the Recipes page for the review in line 2 in the Reviews (the recipe ID is NOT found anywhere in Column C on the Recipes page). A format condition must return True or False, so we test whether that statement returns `#NA!` with the statement `=ISNA(MATCH($C2, Recipes!$C:$C, 0))`. That returns True if the match is NOT found, which gives us the format condition we need for row 2. Set the conditional format to Red Fill when the statement holds.

Apply that condition to the the entire list on the Reviews page. Any row on the Reviews page with an ID that is not on the Recipes page will meet the condition.

Note that any empty Review rows will also turn red. Avoiding that can be built into the format condition with `IF($C2 <> "", ...)`. I'll ignore that here in order to keep this simple. I'm just aiming for enough to get you headed in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

To implement conditional formatting in Xlwings, you need to use `FormatConditions.Add`
This will allow you to create a Formatting Rule and apply the formula provided by @Richard Cook across the necessary range and set the fill colour.

**Code example**

1. First open the workbook ( called foo.xlsx in this example ) and set the sheet name. I cannot duplicate the names of your sheets therefore I'm calling the first [screenshot] Sheet 'Recipes' and the second [screenshot] sheet 'Reviews'.
2. Set the range the formatting will apply to. This can just be the column the IDs are in e.g. Column C, another column or the whole row, e.g. columns A to F. In this example I'm applying to the row therefore the column range A:F, excluding the header row, of the data in your example sheet. The used range is A2:F6, obviously if there are more rows then you can expand this range.
3. Create the cf Rule;
   `FormatConditionType`; `xlExpression` sets the Rule type to "Use a formula to determine which cells to format"
   The next param is not used after setting the `FormatConditionType` so it's set to 0
   The last param is the formula to use in the conditional formatting.
4. Next step is to set the fill colour. For this, standard Red is used.
5. Save the workbook. Since this example is using a context manager there is no need to include any close or quit statements.

Screenshot of Reviews sheet after the code example is run
[image]

I have changed the value of the recipe_id in row 4 to match an id in the Recipe sheet so the row is not filled. The other rows which do not match an id are all highlighted.

```
import xlwings as xw
from xlwings.constants import FormatConditionType as FormCondTp
from xlwings.utils import rgb_to_int

filepath = 'foo.xlsx'
with xw.App(visible=False) as app:
    wb = xw.Book(filepath)
    ws = wb.sheets['Reviews']

    cf_rng = ws.api.Range("$A2:$F6")  # Highlight row, cols A - F
    # cf_rng = ws.api.Range("$C2:$C6")    # Highlight 'recipe_id' column only

    cf_rng.FormatConditions.Add(FormCondTp.xlExpression, 0, '=ISNA(MATCH($C2,Recipes!$C:$C,0))')
    cf_rng.FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = rgb_to_int((255, 0, 0))  # Convert RGB colour

    wb.save('out_foo.xlsx')
```